# String Name; Method 1: Atleast 2 words, max 4 words, no special signs and only letters

Tags: java, string

I've been searching around and havn't quite found my answer.

At this moment me and along with my group have created a few classes resembling a Bank with Customer and Account and so on.

I've been struggling lately with trying to improve and secure our code by making our variable called "name" only respond to certain inputs.

In this case, I want to make it only possible for the person to enter name as such:
Atleast 2 words   =  (For the word part I've seen codes where you count towards the white space between but don't know yet what you do about the last word since there wont be a white space)

Max 4 words  = ( Same thing here)

No special signs such as ,!%¤"#()=%/'¨.    =    ( for this, I've read something about "Matcher and pattern" )

Now I'm quite new to Java and I'm not asking for a code from someone, I'm asking for someone to point me in the right directions regarding codes, because alot of what i've seen like the Matcher and pattern are things that you import with downloading utils and stuff but I reckon that it's not needed and there should be a simpler more basic way as I'm not trying to get ahead of myself with copying codes just to get it done.

So yeah, the String "name" is used alot in our main class "Banklogic" where almost every method that adds something has the variable "name" in it, so it's quite important that I get this done.

I hope I was clear enough and any help would be appreciated! I'm gonna put the alarm for 3 hours before school to see what you guys have come up with so I can try and complete the code before our meeting! Thanks alot in advance :)

Comment: This question has definitely been answered before. You can use this thing called Regex. You can read about it on the java documentation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [Take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) after that, learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and finally post a [runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy-paste. You're asking a too broad question without code. Stack Overflow isn't a site for solving this kind of questions but specific problems and let others learn from this, not solving your problems while guessing what might be wrong while you sleep

Comment: `Brian O'Conner`, `François Hollande` and `安倍 晋三` will not approve of your definition of allowed names.

Comment: @Kaosutanpaus I almost forgot... a little while ago I wrote such a class for myself while learning regex. Maybe you would like to have a look? Details added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for hints, you can use [Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to add such rules.

For Numbers only:

```
if(string.matches("[0-9\\W]")
    //allow insertion of data else not
```

As for rules related Word Count:

`string.split("\\W")` will create an array separated by `space` character. You can count the number of elements in this array and allow/disallow input based on that.

As for no signs and only letters:

```
if(string.matches("[a-zA-Z\\W]")
   // Allow Input else not
```

You can use [Document Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to implement these methods. Document filter will only allow text to be entered if you allow it to.

I hope this helped as a hint.

Also, note that `\\W` is for whitespaces. If you dont want to allow whitespaces, remove that char.

This is the most effective and simple way of doing the task.

**EDIT:**

[This is a Class](https://github.com/Jaskaranbir/JCustomTextField/blob/master/JCustomTextField.java) I wrote a little while ago to achieve such tasks. Just in case if you are interested....